# Set Wallet Address to Crowdsale Address

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, crowdsale

I am using an openZepplin crowdsale contract which has the following constructor

```
contract myContract is Crowdsale {
    function myContract 
    (
        uint256 _rate,
        address _wallet,
        MintableToken _token
    )
        public
        Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
}
```

I want to make my "_wallet" address the same as the "myContract" address.
Is there a way to get the current contract address within the contract?

Sudo code would be something alongs these lines:

```
contract myContract is Crowdsale {
    function myContract 
    (
        uint256 _rate,
        address _wallet,
        MintableToken _token
    )
        public
        Crowdsale(_rate, <<this.address>>, _token)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass `this` ir `address(this)` (which is the same) but it won't work. It seems it thinks you are trying to deploy an abstract contract. As for *why*, I don't know yet and I am looking into it.

This is what you are basically trying to do. As I said, it won't work.

```
contract A {
    address public my_address;

    function A(address _val) {
        my_address= _val;
    }
}

contract B is A {
    function B() {
        A(this);
    }
}
```

To make it work, you will have to modify your contracts and do the following :

```
contract A {
    address public my_address;

    function A() {
        my_address= this;
    }
}

contract B is A {
    function B() {
      //do more stuff
    }
}
```

If you deploy it on Remix, you will see that `my_address` will have the correct value.

Comment: Yes. Exactly, your first example is where is spent a good chunk of my day today. Thanks for the advice, this is very helpful, I will attempt to use this approach

Comment: Alternatively. Since B inherits from A, my_address is available in B. So I can just rewrite it there in "function B". Its pretty hacky, but it will prevent me from changing the OpenZepplin code.